# mGoogleApiClient.isConnected returns false even after mGoogleApiClient.connect

Tags: android, authentication, google-signin, android-authenticator

I am using google sign in for authentication.

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .requestProfile()
        .build();

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this, this)
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
```

Whenever user launches the app I am checking if the session is still available.

```
if (isGoogleSignedIn()) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

Upon onConnected callback, I am launching the next activity.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    GlobalUtils.googleApiClient = mGoogleApiClient;
    launchNextActivity();
}
```

I am saving the reference to mGoogleApiClient in my GlobalUtils to make user sign out implementation easier. Following is my logoutUser method.

```
public static void logOutUser() {

    // Google logout
    if (googleApiClient != null && googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(googleApiClient);
    }

    googleApiClient = null;
}
```

But here the trouble is, googleApiClient.isConnected() always returns false as soon as I leave the login activity. I am making sure that googleApiClient.connect() is always called before the user enters the app main activity.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first activity isn't calling `disconnect` in one of the lifecycle events right? e.g. in `onPause` or `onStop`

Comment: No, it is not calling disconnect.

Comment: Are you sure to make only one instance of mGoogleApiClient?

Comment: Yes, I am very sure.

Answer (score -3):

I think the problem is you not connect google api client. Try connect whenever you use google api, and disconnect when you no use anymore. Hope this help.